# PYTHON ujson. ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pip, rasa, pep

I`m trying to install RASA framework on my Windows laptop using Poetry and build from source. Using pip wont help me as i was never able to install Tensorflow and it comes along with RASA.

What i have done already:

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
$ git clone https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa.git
$ cd rasa
$ poetry install
```

When the installation reach the point to install ujson this happens and the installation stops:

```
Collecting ujson
  Using cached ujson-2.0.3.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: ujson
  Building wheel for ujson (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for ujson (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\claudiu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\claudiu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\claudiu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3514zx41'
       cwd: C:\Users\claudiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2qy6btub\ujson
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ujson' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\deps
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\deps\double-conversion
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\deps\double-conversion\double-conversion
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\lib
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\python
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -Ic:\users\claudiu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\claudiu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /EHsc /Tp./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.obj -D_GNU_SOURCE
  bignum-dtoa.cc
  ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.cc(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'math.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
Failed to build ujson
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Probably I can could simply install Anaconda and get it done that way (tensorflow worked this way), however the project I want to build needs to be able to run outside of Anaconda at any given time.

Can anyone help me please?
By the way, i already installed latest Microsoft Visual C++ and build tools.

Answer (score 5):

there may be two issue in window

1. if bit issue if you are installing in machine 32bit inplace of 64bit use this
   https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/#step-by-step-installation-guide
2. ujson compatibility issue discussed here : https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson/issues/369

download your whl file from: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ujson](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ujson)

a)pip install ujson-1.35-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

b)pip install rasa

Comment: try these steps rasa official                                                                                                   1) conda create --name installrasa python==3.7.6
2) activate installrasa
3) conda install ujson
4) conda install tensorflow
5) pip install rasa 
rasa init

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the current version of ujson

```
conda uninstall ujson
```

and try installing the ujson - 1.35

```
conda install ujson==1.35
```