# Error while installing Rasa on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, rasa-nlu, rasa

Heyy! I am having this nagging error every time I try to install rasa on my windows 10 pc. I have a ton of different methods but couldn't solve it. I am attaching a screenshot of the actual error message if you could help me out, I would be extremely thankful.

I am working on anaconda prompt and have already installed ujson and tensorflow in my virtual environment. Also, the python version in my virtual environment is 3.6 which is the recommended version to use with Rasa.

```
    Building wheels for collected packages: ujson
  Building wheel for ujson (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\envs\env2\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzyo8y2hx'
       cwd: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-99mhzaz9\ujson
  Complete output (5 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ujson' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
Failed to build ujson
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I am sorry, but I am new to programming and I am not familiar with the language used to show errors. I can't understand what is wrong, and what should I do? Please answer me if you understand anything from it.

*As you may have sensed from my knowledge, I am a newbie to python and working environment so...*
**KINDLY GIVE ME A STEP BY STEP GUIDE TO SUCCESSFULLY INSTALL RASA ON MY WINDOWS PC.**
Thanking you in advance!

***After installing Microsoft C++ 14 I am getting a new error as down below: *** KINDLY HELP!!

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\envs\env2\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\envs\env2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpogffct0b'
       cwd: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f5lmobk0\ujson
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ujson' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\deps
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\deps\double-conversion
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\deps\double-conversion\double-conversion
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\lib
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\python
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -IC:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\envs\env2\include -IC:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\envs\env2\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include /EHsc /Tp./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.obj -D_GNU_SOURCE
  bignum-dtoa.cc
  ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.cc(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'math.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
Failed to build ujson
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

["New Error message after installing Visual studio C++ 14"][2]

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what to do. just read it

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @luigigi I am not able to understand the language..can u please formulate it for me. Actually, I am a first year C.S. student and have never programmed before so, I am not good with understanding errors. I'd appreciate if you could give me a proper answer.

Comment: @Scratte Sorry for my bad question... actually, I don't have much experience with using this website and also programming in general. I am just starting out and I hope to learn from experienced people like yourself. I will keep your advice in my mind when I ask my next question.

Comment: get microsoft visual c++ 14.0 or greater

Comment: Where's also [Python 3 Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/) explaining the same thing as your error message is saying.

Comment: @luigigi I am getting a new problem after installing Microsoft visual c++ 14. Pls, check my question again for details. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Scratte Installed it but now there is a new error. Pls, check my question again for details. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [C1083: Cannot open include file: math.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186647/c1083-cannot-open-include-file-math-h-no-such-file-or-directory)?

Comment: @Scratte how are these two questions related at all???

Comment: It's the same error message, though I must admit that [PYTHON ujson. ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573883/python-ujson-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-ujson-which-use-pep-517-and-cann) is basically identical to your new error.

Comment: @scratte This question is still not solved if anyone knows something kindly tell me.

Comment: Your Question is identical to the other one. If anyone know how to solve if, they would have already posted or will in the future post an Answer on the other Question.